# How to write audio track information to the file, using Banshee

Tags: banshee, music, metadata, mp3-tag

As the title suggests, when I change audio track information (metadata) in Banshee I want it to be stored **to the file** and I can't figure out how to do it.  Maybe this cannot be achieved in Banshee

**Problem**

When I copy audio files to other devices (like a smart phone) in does not retain the metadata changes I applied in Banshee.  I am assuming there is some hidden database in ~/home that stores this data.  Is there away I can do this in Banshee or do i need to download some other software package.  The primary purpose of this question is to understand how it can be done in Banshee.  I am not looking for a list of alternative software music taggers unless the definitive answer is **No**.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Banshee, choose Edit > Preferences from the menu at the top. In the General tab of the Preferences dialog window, there should be an option named "Sync metadata between library and files".  Make sure this option is checked.

As far as I know, this option won't retroactively update metadata for files that you've previously updated in Banshee, but it will write metadata to the files for any future updates you make.

Comment: That simple, great! Your second paragraph is a really useful comment also.  Only update a picture of you believe it will help others, Im'good with the response as is.